# Warning on "unstable" directive

Tags: rust

Why does Rust gives me a warning when I add the `#![allow(unstable)]` directive?

> unknown `allow` attribute: `unstable`, #[warn(unknown_lints)] on by default

[Playpen example](http://is.gd/tIIk7j)

Answer (score 4):

The unstable lint was removed in [a530cc9706324ad44dba464d541a807eb5afdb08](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/a530cc9706324ad44dba464d541a807eb5afdb08).

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this."  "So stop doing it."  "But you told me to!"  "Ah, well, I changed my mind."  "..."  "Here, have a lollipop."

Answer (score 1):

As Steve points out, the unstable lint was removed. You can find more information in the [Release Channels RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0507-release-channels.md), specifically the section [Merging stability attributes and feature gates](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0507-release-channels.md#merging-stability-attributes-and-feature-gates):

> As a simplifying measure stability attributes are unified with feature gates, and thus tied to release channels and Rust language versions.

And

> With these modifications, new API surface area becomes a new "language feature" which is controlled via the #[feature] attribute just like other normal language features. The compiler will disallow all usage of #[staged_unstable(feature = "foo")] APIs unless the current crate declares #![feature(foo)]. This enables crates to declare what API features of the standard library they rely on without opting in to all unstable API features.